# Why the Block command does not forget the $ContextPath variable

Tags: evaluation

I do not understand this behavior:

```
method[args_] :=
    (* forget the context path *)
    Block[{$ContextPath},
            (* should given nothing, right? *)
         Print["cpath=", $ContextPath];
            ...
```

but when evaluated it gives the full context path (i.e. it does not forgets it). Why is that? This is against everything I (seem to) know about the `Block` function.

Comment: Next followup question: "How do I make a special variable like these?" ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I try this, everything gets removed *except* for `` {System`,Global`} ``:

```
In[1]:= $ContextPath

Out[1]= {"PacletManager`", "QuantityUnits`", "WebServices`", "System`", "Global`"}

In[2]:= Block[{$ContextPath}, Print[$ContextPath]]

During evaluation of In[2]:= {System`,Global`}
```

My guess is that this is a special exception which is implemented to make `$ContextPath` usable like this:

```
Block[{$ContextPath}, Needs["SomePackage`"]]
```

This loads the package without adding it to the context path.  It's quite useful with Combinatorica in version 8 and later.

It *is* in fact possible to remove `` System` `` and `` Global` `` from `$ContextPath` but this just breaks the system completely and would also make it impossible to load any packages.  You can (**in a new session, where you won't lose work!!**) try `$ContextPath = {}` and render the system unusable if you are using a notebook interface.  The reason why package loading would be broken is that `` System` `` context symbols would need to be referenced by the full name, as in `` System`Sin ``, which packages don't do.

So I think this is a special exception to the behaviour of `Block`/`$ContextPath` that makes the above use case possible.

Comment: +1 for tip on loading w/o adding to path.

Comment: @rasher I learned it form Leonid but I don't remember in which answer.

Comment: @rasher Probably Szabolcs referred to [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5563/how-to-load-a-package-without-naming-conflicts/5574#5574).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Precisely.

Comment: That was fast :)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Typical LS cleverness ;-}  
Thanks for reference.

Comment: I think ``Global` `` can be removed without problems.

Answer (score 13):

There are some "special variables" in *Mathematica* that cannot be cleared. These are fundamentally necessary for its operation and while it will let you revert to a *default* value inside a `Block`, it will not allow you to clear it.

You can verify this directly, without `Block`:

```
Clear@$ContextPath
```

> Clear::spsym: Special symbol $ContextPath cannot be cleared. >>

It doesn't work even though `$ContextPath` is not `Protected` or `Locked`.

---

You can find out which other symbols are special:

```
Reap[Quiet@Check[Clear@#, Sow@#, Clear::spsym] & /@ 
    Select[Names["System`*"], FreeQ[Attributes@#, Protected] &]] // Last // Last

(* {$ActivationGroupID,$ActivationKey,$ActivationUserRegistered,$AssertFunction,$Assumptions,
 $BatchInput,$BoxForms,$CharacterEncoding,$Context,$ContextPath,$HistoryLength,$InputFileName,
 $InstallationDirectory,$IterationLimit,$Language,$LicenseExpirationDate,$LicenseID,
 $LicenseProcesses,$LicenseServer,$LicenseSubprocesses,$LicenseType,$LoadedFiles,
 $MachineAddresses,$MachineDomain,$MachineDomains,$MachineID,$MachineName,$MaxExtraPrecision,
 $MaxLicenseProcesses,$MaxLicenseSubprocesses,$MaxPiecewiseCases,$MaxPrecision,$MaxRootDegree,
 $MinPrecision,$ModuleNumber,$NetworkLicense,$NumberMarks,$ParentLink,$ParentProcessID,
 $PasswordFile,$PatchLevelID,$Path,$ProcessID,$RandomState,$RecursionLimit,
 $TemporaryDirectory,$TemporaryPrefix,$TopDirectory,$TraceOff,$TraceOn,$TracePattern,
 $TracePostAction,$TracePreAction,$UserBaseDirectory,$UserName} *)
```

From a quick look at what's in the list, you can easily see that most of these are critical for the software to function.