# Using packages with symbols that have the same name

Tags: packages, symbols, contexts

Let us suppose we have two packages: A and B.

```
BeginPackage["A`"]

Foo::usage="bla bla";

Begin["`Private`"]

Foo[x_]:= x^2;
SetAttributes[Foo,{Protected,ReadProtected,Locked}];

End[]
EndPackage[]
```

.

```
BeginPackage["B`"]

Foo::usage="bla bla";

Begin["`Private`"]

Foo[x_]:= x^3;
SetAttributes[Foo,{Protected,ReadProtected,Locked}];

End[]
EndPackage[]
```

Obviously, if the user tries to load both packages on the same kernel, there
will be shadowing issues. Normally one would just rename one of the functions
to avoid that kind of conflicts. However, if both packages come from different developers and are encrypted/proprietary (i.e. there is no way to modify the source code) then the user seems to be out of luck.

So is there any possibility to load the two packages on the same kernel such, that the functions `Foo` from A and B will not go into the `Global` context? Then the user could use just `` A`Foo `` and `` B`Foo `` to distinguish between the two. Or are there possibly other tricks to have both functions in the **same** session?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  `Foo` *will not* go in the ``Global` `` context.  If you evaluate the code you posted in a newly started kernel, you'll get ``A`Foo`` and ``B`Foo`` and you can refer to them as such.  You will not get ``Global`Foo``.  Simply typing `Foo` will refer to ``B`Foo`` because package B was loaded last and thus ``B` `` appears first in `$ContextPath`.

Comment: @Szabolcs You're of course correct, there's nothing going into `Global`  here. My mistake. But I'm mainly worried about the warning messages that Mathematica issues when I load both packages. Can I really ignore them (in this case) without any issues? That would mean that I can essentially do `Off[General::shdw];` `Needs["A`"];` `Needs["B`"];` `On[General::shdw]` without any problems, right?

Comment: and with the help of ``$ContextPath = 
  Select[$ContextPath, (! StringMatchQ[#, "A`" ~~ ___] && ! 
       StringMatchQ[#, "B`" ~~ ___]) &];`` I can ensure that there will be no confusion between `Foo` from `A` and `B`. Hmm, this seems to be much easier than I thought.

Comment: You don't need `StringMatchQ`.  `$ContextPath` should simply contain ``"A`"``, not ``A` `` followed by something.  If you like, just use ``DeleteCases[$ContextPath, "A`"|"B`"]``

Comment: at least related seems this [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/312/169) of mine and all answers to it:

Comment: @AlbertRetey Thanks, that's quite interesting. There are, however, cases when things may still go wrong, e.g. if both packages modify Mathematica's functions (`D`, `Dot`, `Times` etc. ) or put their variables explicitly into the global context. In this situation the safest thing (in my view) would be to start those packages on parallel kernels and communicate with them via `ParallelEvaluate`.  Although I'm sure that I'm not the first one who got that idea.

Comment: yes, Mathematica lets you do a lot of things with namespaces and global/system symbols. It probably shouldn't allow all that but that's how things are, and I guess they'd be really hard to change. IMO code for others to use shouldn't make use of all these possibilities and if foreign code does stuff like modify system symbols or add symbols to "Global`" or other foreign contexts it probably makes sense to complain or avoid such code. Running parts of your code in a parallel kernel just to avoid shading problems seems an extreme kind of workaround, but might be justified if all else fails...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the comments:

> But I'm mainly worried about the warning messages that Mathematica issues when I load both packages.

If the packages are properly written, and if the symbol conflict is between two packages (and not builtins and a package function), then you can safely ignore it.

From the documentation of [`BeginPackage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BeginPackage.html):

> `` BeginPackage["context`"] `` makes `` context` `` and `` System` `` the only active contexts.

This means that when package B is loading, it should be completely unaware of the existence (or any symbol definitions from) package A.  So there will be no conflict.  This is not the case if there's a conflict with `` System` `` symbols, as that context is still active and visible to package B during load time.

I'm assuming that the packages follow the standard structure and don't make unusual use of `$Context`, `$ContextPath` or `BeginPackage`.

---

There's a trick you might find useful:

```
Block[{$ContextPath}, Needs["B`"]]
```

will load package B without adding it to the `$ContextPath`.  To use functions from B, now you *must* refer them with their full name, including the context name.  The shadowing message won't be issued because there's no shadowing anymore.  There's no ambiguity when resolving symbol names typed without a context.

Aside: You might wonder why this `Block` works at all, [here's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43137/12) a question about that.

Comment: +1 btw, you seem to have left off the link to the question about `Block`.

Comment: Thanks, now I feel much more comfortable working with packages that use the same names! The only thing where this probably might go wrong, is when both packages would define ``Global`Foo[x_]:=...``. Although it's not a good practice, I've already seen some packages doing that.

Comment: @Szabolcs I also would like to see the link to the question about `Block`. Could you please add it?

Comment: @vsht Fixed the link, sorry about that.  It's not particularly interesting, it's just good to point out that `Block` doesn't in fact clear `$ContextPath`, so this doesn't break the code within.  Also not that `$ContextPath` affects *parsing*, not evaluation.  Thus the code literally written inside the `Block` won't be affected.  But the code loaded by `Needs` *will* be because it is parsed only after the `$ContextPath`-change has taken effect.